# Which type library should I import to use Microsoft Open XML?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'd like to start using Microsoft Open XML API with Delphi 2009 to create MS Excel documents. I downloaded and installed Microsoft Open XML but how to proceed further? I thought I can import type library after the installation but I can't find the library on the list. Which one should I import?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. Could you be more specific.

Comment: I need to create Excel document containing sheets with easy tables. I wanted to use OLE Automation but then I realized I was building Win32 service which should not interact with the desktop. Microsoft writes on it's pages Excel OLE Automation is not recommended and even supported on servers because it sometimes requires user interaction. I'v found MS Open XML and I hoped it could resolve my situation.

Comment: You want to use [Open XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx)? Is that correct? I suspect that APZ28 is correct in that this is a .net library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was try to use it but it is for .net only (there is no exported COM info/com implementation)